# Proper treatment of springs in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, spring, statics

I've looked on-line for a simple treatment of springs under tension/compression while moving at relativistic velocities parallel to the direction of tension/compression and could not find one. There have been several recent posts involving springs and special relativity and I wanted to make sure I understand. I have a solution that makes three assumptions:

1. The spring constant will be measured differently in the two frames
2. It's a statics problem: The sum of the forces in both reference frames is zero.
3. The spring is massless, frictionless and obeys Hookes law.

Are these valid assumptions?

Here's my solution:
Imagine a spring stretched to a length greater than it's rest length and attached between two fixed points (like the ends of the pole in the pole-barn paradox)

In a non-accelerating reference frame at rest:

$$F - k(r-r_o) = 0$$

If the measurements are performed on a non-accelerating reference frame moving at velocity v parallel to the direction of stretching, then

$$F'-k'(r'-r_o') = 0$$

The spring constant is measured in $\frac{Newtons}{meter}$ and since a meter is measured differently at rest than at relativistic speeds any length contractions must be applied to the spring constant.

Since the reference frames are not accelerating with respect to each other then:

$$F'-k'(r'-r_o') = F-k(r-r_o) = 0$$

$$ r_o' = \frac{r_o}{\gamma}$$
$$r' = \frac{r}{\gamma}$$
$$ k' = k\gamma $$

$$F'-F = k\gamma(\frac{r}{\gamma} -\frac{r_o}{\gamma}) -k(r-r_o)$$

The $\gamma$ terms cancel yielding:

$$F = F'$$

Both observers will measure the same force.

Comment: Please make it clear if you are talking about a spring where both ends are at rest in a given reference frame (the static case as per assumption 2) or if the ends have relative velocity to each other  (the dynamic case).

Comment: Hi @KDP  both ends of the spring are fixed and the spring is under compression. The fixed spring system is traveling at relativistic speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your analysis is essentially correct, but is only valid for springs and forces parallel to the relative motion. Let's generalise it a bit more but remain with the static case where the proper force is not varying in the rest frame:

Assumptions:

1. Force transforms as per the Lorentz transformation of ***static*** force.
2. Length transforms as per the Lorentz transformation of Length.
3. The springs obey Hooke's law in the rest frame of the spring.

In the rest frame of the spring, we have:

$$ k = F /  r $$

where (r) is the difference between the length of the stretched spring and length of the spring when it is not under stress. To an observer moving relative to the rest frame of the spring:

$$ k'_{\parallel} = F'_{\parallel} / r'_{\parallel} = (F_{\parallel} )/ (r'_{\parallel} \gamma^{-1}) = k \gamma$$

$$ k'_{\perp} = F'_{\perp} / r'_{\perp} = (F_{\perp} \gamma^{-1}) / (r_{\perp}) = k \gamma^{-1}$$

so I agree with your conclusion that the spring constant is not Lorentz invariant.

The relativistic form of Hooke's law becomes:

$$ F'_{\parallel} = k'_{\parallel} \ r'_{\parallel} =  (k \gamma)  \ (r_{\parallel} \gamma^{-1} ) = k \ r_{\parallel} = F_{\parallel}$$

$$ F'_{\perp} = k'_{\perp} \ r'_{\perp} =  (k \gamma^{-1})  \ (r_{\perp}) = k \ r_{\perp} \ \gamma^{-1} = F_{\perp} \gamma^{-1}$$

Comment: The case for static springs under tension is already solved and exemplified by the fairly well known "Right Angle Lever Paradox" of relativity. Bear in mind clocks and rulers can have mass, but the Lorentz transformation of time and length are independent of the mass of the clocks or rulers.

Comment: Thans for your help. I'm glad I had it right the first time. This is a link to a paper that yields the same results using a four-vector stress/strain approach: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252618282_Covariant_formulation_of_Hooke's_law

Answer (score 2):

When you wrote the spring constant as being an expression of Force per Length (fine) and then defined the Force part to be frame-invariant (not fine), you *defined* spring force to be a frame-invariant.

Your conclusion that the **net** forces are equal in all frames is true, but only because you've chosen the net force to be 0. If you had any other net force, you'd have a false conclusion.

To generalize beyond this special case, express with (for forces in general including the net force, the spring force, and the third-law counterpart of the spring force)

$\vec F = \gamma^3 m\vec a_{\parallel} + \gamma m\vec a_{\perp}$