# $\mathbf F'=\mathbf F$ in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, symmetry

Assume that an inertial observer $S'$ is moving with a velocity $\mathbf u$ relative to another inertial observer $S$ along the $x-$axis.

Now, imagine that the two observers observe a force being applied on an object, also along the $x-$axis.

Can we conclude that $\mathbf F',$ the force $S'$ observes is identical to $\mathbf F,$ the force $S$ observes, **without getting into Lorentz transformations**?

I know that the force is form-invariant, i.e
$$\mathbf F = \frac{d\mathbf p}{dt}\\
\mathbf F' = \frac{d\mathbf p'}{dt'},$$ but I don't think this is useful since we can't relate the RHS's.

This has something to do with symmetry. I thought about making the two observers collide with one another and using the symmetry and Newton's third law (assuming the system is isolated) but this makes the frames non-inertial. It would probably have something to do with light, but I can't think of an experiment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.sciencebits.com/Transformation-Forces-Relativity, https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Four-force

Comment: This may be helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/802112/334569

Answer (score 1):

The covariant Minkowski force can be written in terms of the three-vector force as
\begin{equation}
{\cal F}^\mu=\left[\gamma\frac{dW}{dt},\gamma{\bf F}\right],
\end{equation}
where $\bf F$ is three-vector force, defined by
\begin{equation}
{\bf F}=\frac{d{\bf p}}{dt}.
\end{equation}